# ExtractParameters in Solrnet (AbstractMethodError)

Tags: c#, .net, solr, solrnet

I'm trying to extract pdf data with **solrnet** client. My code is the following:

```
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream((byte[])dataReader["file_stream"]))
                    {
                        var solr = ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<ISolrOperations<Contribution>>();
                        ExtractParameters extract = new ExtractParameters(stream, "doc1", dataReader["nome_original"] + "")
                        {
                            ExtractOnly = true,
                            ExtractFormat = ExtractFormat.Text/*,
                            StreamType = "application/pdf"*/
                        };
                        var response = solr.Extract(extract);
                        Debug.WriteLine("\n+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++ " + response.Content);
                    }
```

However Im getting the error you can see below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

                at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.sendError(HttpSolrCall.java:604)

                at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:473)

                at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:225)

                at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilter.java:183)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1652)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:585)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:143)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:577)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doHandle(SessionHandler.java:223)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1127)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:515)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.session.SessionHandler.doScope(SessionHandler.java:185)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1061)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:215)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:110)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:97)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:499)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:310)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:257)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$2.run(AbstractConnection.java:540)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:635)

                at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:555)

                at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError

                at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(ContentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)

                at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandlerBase.java:155)

                at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:2082)

                at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.execute(HttpSolrCall.java:670)

                at org.apache.solr.servlet.HttpSolrCall.call(HttpSolrCall.java:458)

                ... 22 more
```

Basically `dataReader["file_stream"]` is a BLOB in the database and I want to get all the text in this file.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: https://github.com/mausch/SolrNet/issues/234

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already fix it. It was a bad installation of JARS.

I was adding:

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex="solr-cell-\d.*\.jar" />
```

and

```
<lib dir="../../../dist/" regex=".*\.jar" />
```

As I had two JARS (**apache-solr-cell-3.5.0** and **solr-cell-5.5.0**) solr was confused which one to choose generating the **AbstractMethodError**.